# Azure DIsk Management

Tags: azure, disk

I just started using azure virtual machines and I must admit I still have a few questions regarding the disk management:
I manage my machines via the Node JS API in the following way:

```
 azure vm create INSTANCE  b39f27a8b8c64d52b05eac6a62ebad85__Ubuntu-12_10-amd64-server-    20130227-en-us-30GB  azureuser XXXXXX --ssh  --location "West US" -t ./azure.pem 
 azure vm start INSTANCE

 //do whatever
 azure vm shutdown INSTANCE
 azure vm delete INSTANCE
```

1. After deleting the instance I still have a buch of disks left, which are not deleted but which I am charged (i.e. deducted from my free trial). Are they not deleted by default?
   Is there an API call to delete them (only found the corresponding REST calls, but kind of unwilling to mix NODE JS and Rest api calls).
2. Can I specify one of those existing disks when starting a new instance?

Thanks for your answers!
Jörg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After deleting the instance I still have a buch of disks left, which are not deleted but which I am charged (i.e. deducted from my free trial). Are they not deleted by default? Is there an API call to delete them (only found the corresponding REST calls, but kind of unwilling to mix NODE JS and Rest api calls).

Yes, the disks are not deleted by default. I believe the reason for that is to reuse those disks to spin off new VMs. To delete the disk (which is a page blob stored in Windows Azure Blob Storage) you could possibly use Azure SDK for Node: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-node.

> Can I specify one of those existing disks when starting a new
>   instance?

Yes, you can. For that you would need to find the disk image and then use the following command:

```
azure vm create myVM myImage myusername --location "West US"
```

Where "myImage" is the name of the image. For more details, please visit: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/#VMs

Answer (score 1):

Yes when a VM is deleted the disk is left behind. Within the portal you can apply this disk image to a new VM instance on creation. There's some specific guidance on creating VMs from the API with existing disk images here:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/how-to-guides/command-line-tools/#VMs